# Add glyphicpn to input field

Tags: css, glyphicons

I have some css that puts a glyphicon at the beggining of an input field. It works but the value of the glyphicon is incorrect and I cannot find the padlock?

The code is :

```
.usericon input{
padding-left:25px;
}
.usericon:before{
    opacity:.8;
    height:100%;
    width:25px;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    content:"\e033";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

The problem is that \e008 isn't correct it's actually 2709. How can I find this value for the padlock?

Comment: searching for glyph unicode is off-topic in SO..despite of the fact you can take a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288572/unicode-glyph-for-padlock]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode Glyph for Padlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288572/unicode-glyph-for-padlock)